NVIDIA driver install on Ubuntu 22.04 left me with no Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, touchpad
I've been using the non-proprietary drivers for a while but wanted to give a shot to the NVIDIA ones. After installing the "recommended, tested" drivers for my GeForce GTX 1650 and upon boot I was met with the scary black screen and blinking cursor.
I managed to open a terminal from there, purge nvidia, restore to previous drivers and everything seemed fine until Ubuntu actually booted.
My touchpad was not working, Wi-Fi wasn't either, Bluetooth either and who knows what else...
I tried some things, I don't even remember anymore...
Made a back-up and decided to re-install Ubuntu...I tried several times but didn't work. I don't think it was correctly recoginizing the usb bootable.
Any help of what I could try would be greatly appreciated....

In terminal try sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)  reboot
